# App Store - Refund when a user upgrades a subscription on app store?

Tags: ios-appstore

When a user upgrades, do they

1. receive an actual refund for the unused portion (prorated) of their original sub in their original form of payment and then charged the full amount of the upgrade?
   OR
2. the unused amount of the original sub is applied to the upgrade subscription?

example:

Original Sub - $100

90% of the subscription period is unused when they upgrade to higher tier sub, which costs $200.

1. is $90 refunded to the user in their bank account and then the user charged $200?
2. the $90 is credited to the upgrade purchase and the user is charged $110  ($200 - $90)

Comment: Based on my reading my receipts, the amount is applied to the new subscription as "Store Credit"